# How to display data from other tables in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using Database-First approach in MVC 4 web application using EF5. I have the following tables in my context:

```
**Employee** <br>
EmpId <br>
StatusId
```

One of the rows of the Employee table is :

```
EmpId=1<br>
StatusId=1
```

**Options**

```
OptionId<br>
OptionListName<br>
OptionName<br>
OptionValue<br>
```

One of the rows of the Options Table is as follows:

```
OptionId=1
OptionListName="Status"
OptionName="Active"
OptionValue=1
```

I created a view for my EmployeeController that displays some fields from Employee table as follows:

```
Employee
----------- 
EmpId     StatusId
1            1
```

However I need to view the table as follows:

```
Employee
-----------
EmpId       Status
1            Active
```

How can I do this in MVC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Viewmodel that takes `IEnumerable<Employee>` and if you only have one Options you need a `Options`. The Viewmodel will look like this:

```
public class YourNamedViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public Options Options { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view you change your model to

```
@using PathTo.ViewModel
@model YourNamedViewModel

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employees.EmpId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Options.OptionListName)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Employees)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                item.EmpId
            </td>
                @if (item.StatusId == 1)
                {
                    <td>
                        <span>@Model.Options.OptionName</span>
                    </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>
                        <span>Inactive</span>
                    </td>
                }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

If you have any other Status modes you need an `IEnumerable<Options>` in your View model and find the corresponding Options that has same OptionId as the Employee.

Haven't been able to test it, but it should work.

Comment: But what if I have these options already existing in a table like in my question ?

Comment: I hope this edited answer works better for you. Another way to handle Options like that would be to make it an enum that's called Options and has Active, Inactive and all the status modes you want. That way you get your header Status by the name of the Enum and Id through the value each Enum item has and you can then show the Status Name by setting a [Display(Name = "Status Name")] on each Enum item.

Comment: No problem. I hope it helped!